# In ASP.NET MVC, how to set one error message for all required fields in class without copy/paste?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have the following model:

```
public class Human
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public String FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public String LastName { get; set; }

    // 50 more required fields not shown for brevity
}
```

If a user doesn't fill out a required field, I would like the error message to be "This field is required". However, I don't want to annotate every single one with `[Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]` because that takes a lot of copy/pasting.

**Is there a way to tell ASP.NET MVC that all required fields in ONLY THIS CLASS should have the error message "This field is required"?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a way to accomplish this. I think it is not possible.